# jQuery hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to sync hovering in two diferente tables... but for some reason when only the first part of the function works, adding the second part breaks the first part and gives me no errors.

I did not put it into the jsfiddle because its not a visual thing... its pure code that's breaking somewhere.

```
$(function(){
    //first part
        var trsCont = $('#conteudo table tr');
        for (i = 0; i < trsCont.length; i++) {
            trsCont.eq(i).hover(
                function () {
                    $('#coluna_fixa table tr').eq(i-1).toggleClass("hovered");
                    }
                );
            }
        //second part   
        var trsCol = $('#coluna_fixa table tr');
        for (i = 0; i < trsCol.length; i++) {
            trsCol.eq(i).hover(
                function () {
                    $('#conteudo table tr').eq(i+1).toggleClass("hovered");
                }
            );
        }
});
```

I know I am doing something wrong... can someone just point it out?

Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: If you take the first part out, does the second part work?

Comment: You really shouldnt define event handlers inside of loops

Comment: ... especially loops involving global iterator variables :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldnt define event handlers inside of loops. Instead you should make your hover functions more generic, like so:

```
//first part
       $('#table1 tr').hover(
           function () {
               var index = $(this).index();
               $("#table2 tr:eq(" + (index - 1) + ")").toggleClass("hovered");
           }
       );
        //second part   
        $('#table2 tr').hover(
           function () {
               var index = $(this).index();
               $("#table1 tr:eq(" + (index + 1) + ")").toggleClass("hovered");
           }
       );
```

Check out this JSFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cAEWR/2/

Comment: The problem is the logic needed. I need to trigger the hover event on the Table 2 Tr(X-1) when Table 1 Tx(X) is hovered.

Comment: @MBarni Ah, I did not notice that from the original code. Let me modify to JS Fiddle

Comment: Vice-versa must happen too.

Comment: @MBarni Updated. Should work for you now. JSFiddle is updated as well

Comment: Thank you very much! Very fast, constructive, wise coding and teaching.